# AppCompatEditText in new support library v7:23.2.0, retaining the error status?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-appcompat, androiddesignsupport, android-textinputlayout

If we setError to the TextInputLayout in one Fragment, if we go to the other fragments by default showing in Error enabled state. Ones the error is enabled, if we are using the different TextInputLayout in different fragment why that status is retaining. Only common things between the Two Fragment is they are Hosted in same Activity.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
```

Find the sample project to simulate the behaviour. 
[Sample Project Github](https://github.com/pollux-/DesignLibIssue)

Google issue tracker:
[issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196995)

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski did you faced this one ?? Or did you give it a try ? you want a demo I can create and share

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski is that make sense to you now ?? or do you need more details, Please let me know. If you got chance please take a look

Answer (score 0):

This issue got fixed in new support library released today 
V **23.3.0**

Mail from the issue tracker attached

> Updates:
>           Status: Released
>
> Comment #19 on issue 190829 by kiri...@google.com: TextInputLayout
>   setError causes all TILs in the app to have red underline
>   https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190829